# Can you replace $x$ with $x^2$ for any Maclaurin series?

Tags: real-analysis

Let's say I have a Maclaurin series for some function $f(x)$, and to find Maclaurin series $f(x^2)$ can I just substitute $x^2$ for each term Maclaurin series for $f(x)$?

Comment: Yes, normally it is done  .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $$f(x)=\sum_{n\ge0}a_nx^n \text{ for }\vert x \vert < R,$$ then $$f(x^k)=\sum_{n\ge0}a_nx^{nk} \text{ for }\vert x^k \vert < R\text{, i.e.} \vert x \vert <R^{1/k}$$

Answer (score 5):

Yes, because you are evaluating the function at the point $x^2$ instead of just $x$. All you are really doing is chaning the domain of the function, so that if the original radius of convergence was $r$, the new radius of convergence is $\sqrt r$.

Comment: What if $x^2$ is no longer in the radius of convergence?

Comment: Thanks for that. I was thinking of the Taylor series expansions for $e^x$, $\sin x$, etc.

Answer (score 3):

$${{{{{{\mathbf{\text{Yes}.}}}}}}}$$

Comment: The radius of convergence may differ however.

Comment: Just beat me to saying that. What if $x^2$ is no longer in the radius of convergence?

Comment: @Zestylemonzi What you call $x$ you can rename as $y^2$ or $z^3$. The radius of convergence will adapt.

Comment: Doesn't it make a difference that $x^2 \ge 0$?

Comment: @Fourier Transform True, but given the level of the question I think it's worth pointing out in your answer. It's something that can easily be overlooked - i.e just sub in $x^2$ with a value of $x$ that worked previously.

Comment: @GFauxPas Not in the sense of the domain of $x$ unless negative numbers could not be included in the original domain. The actual function values may be restricted, however.